# How to read and/or save Python output in VIM

Tags: python, vim

I'm new to VIM and am using this command to save and run a Python script:

```
:w !python
```

However, I can't move up and down to read the output. The only option I am given is to press enter or enter a command. I tried to yank(`:%y+`) everything, but the actual code is yanked and not the output. I would prefer to be able to read all the output displayed in VIM and even better would be opening a new tab with the output and being able to search and read through all of it.

Comment: I think you have to save using `:w` and then go back and `:!python exec.py` because it doesnt save when I try it.  And when I do that I get proper output displayed in vim, all of it.

Comment: Try :read !python /path/to/myscript.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use redirection just like you normally would to write the output of python running the script into a different file. For instance:

```
:w !python > temp
```

And then

```
:tabnew temp
```

Not sure if there's a way to write the output directly to another buffer or not.

Another option is to save your script to a file (say "script.py") and then switch to your other buffer where you want to see the output, and then filter it like:

```
:%!python script.py
```

It will replace the entire contents of the buffer with the output of your script.

Comment: Works great! Any way to make it into one line? The second one (%!python script.py) gives me the same issues. Also, what is the % for? I used : instead.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it in one line. Normally, you could separate multiple commands with a `|`, but the vim help says that this isn't possible for the `write !` command because it sees the bar as part of it's arguments. But once you open `temp` in a new tab, you can just leave it open and reload it when it changes.

Comment: The `%` at the start of the last code snippet was sort of a mistake, I forgot to incldue the `:`. The `%` just means to filter the entire buffer, as opposed to a specific range. It may not be necessary if you just do `:!`, but it does work.

Comment: Getting back to doing it without two commands: if you leave the output file (`temp`) open in another buffer, you can set the `autoread` option on that buffer and it will automatically reload it any time it changes.

Comment: I tried to do :set autoread on the buffer, didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Place this function in your vimrc.
It will open a window with the captured output (for any command, not just python).

```
function! Redir(cmd)
  for win in range(1, winnr('$'))
    if getwinvar(win, 'scratch')
      execute win . 'windo close'
    endif
  endfor
  if a:cmd =~ '^!'
    let output = system(matchstr(a:cmd, '^!\zs.*'))
  else
    redir => output
    execute a:cmd
    redir END
  endif
  botright vnew
  let w:scratch = 1
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  call setline(1, split(output, "\n"))
endfunction
"`:Redir` followed by either shell or vim command
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Redir silent call Redir(<q-args>)
```

Also in do `:help python` in vim.
There are also plugins for python.