# How to print the output of python code in Vim buffer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, printing

Example (in vim function):

```
python3 << endpython
import vim,sys,locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, vim.eval("Locale"))
for i in range(1,10,2):
    print(locale.format('%.2f', i))
endpython
```

The print command, prints the numbers as an echo message.
I would like to print the numbers at the top of the current buffer.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the current buffer and append after line 0 (= inserting at the top) via:

```
vim.current.buffer.append("example text", 0)
```

See `:help python-buffer`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ingo

Comment: The at the top "0" number reverse the list but it works very fine also without it. It would be nice to use the "0" only for the 1st item. :)

Comment: If you start with an empty buffer, the `0` indeed is optional. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you have this [Redir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58875937/1803897),
you can recover already printed text with:

`:Redir messages`

Example:

```
:py3 print('print to stdout')
:Redir messages
/print to stdout
```

It will be at the end of the buffer that opens.